# Multiple running tasks in windows service with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

Sorry If im not going to be specific but this is my first post as a fresh developer. Im presented with task of creating asp.net web app in C#  that will be interacting with multiple systems around infrastructure. Some of those interactions will be quick and unfortunately some of them will take a long time to finish due amount of queries which will take their time to finish. 
To add complexity some of the tasks when started could take like 8 hours to finish :(

I would appreciate input on idea of :
- having web app as UI 
- having windows service hosting WCF to handle those requests as tasks ?

Any input appreciated

Comment: You might want to consider a pub-sub model on WCF services, possibly using a framework such as NServiceBus.  This kind of setup is good for asynchronous operations where you need to guarantee message reliability.

Comment: Thanks for reply - but I think at the stage of my development this could be a little bit to much for my skills :) I would be keen to investigate concurrency and instancing of WCF to kinda achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) on "One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events" was very helpful for me to learn how to use WCF in different scenarios.

Comment: Hey Steven,thanks for sharing this however I think my comment have sidetrack ppl from original question.which was if its a good idea to look at wcf in windows service or maybe different technology should be used for this task?

Comment: Ah, well, I personally moved away from WCF because I feel it is bulky and not very flexible and I now use [ASP MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/web-api), which I use to expose a very complex distributed system to a web interface. You can also run this framework on cloud services such as [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) or [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/)

For your back-end it does not really matter what web interface you use, because the work has to be done on worker-roles or on servers. However, if you need TCP or MSMQ -> use WCF; in any other case, the ASP MVC 4 framework is better.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Let me research it and see whether it will be indeed better for me to use MVC framework